# WSO2 API Manager "unable to find valid certification path to requested target {org .wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIProviderHostObject}"

Tags: validation, ssl, wso2, wso2-api-manager

We have deployed a WSO2 API Manager to expose the APIs of the system. When we published an API with a https target endpoint (Eg: https://abc.d.e:), the requests get failed with the following exception.

```html
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-06-26 06:46:43,226] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobje
cts.APIProviderHostObject} -  Error occurred while connecting to backend : https
://list-micro.aws.na.sysco.net:9090, reason : sun.security.validator.ValidatorEx
ception: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBu
ilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target {org
.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIProviderHostObject}
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException:
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderExce
ption: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.
java:1514)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.jav
a:216)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1026)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:961)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
```

Comment: Did you load the certificate for the target endpoint into your client-truststore.jks?  If not do that and restart server.

Comment: Should we have to load each and every cert of the target endpoints to trust store jks? In that case, the publisher can not do that right? API publishing is going to be a cumbersome task.

Comment: I am using 1.10 and as far as I am aware that is correct.  You have to load the cert for the endpoints you want to hit otherwise you get the SSL error.  And there is no way to do that in publisher.  If there is something we are missing or new capability in a later version hopefully someone will comment back to us,

Comment: is this the full stack-trace of the exception? If not can you please add that?

Answer (score 0):

Wso2/Carbon uses Java 8 .. Keep in mind there is an issue where the apparently SSL client doesn't pares SNI very well.  So if you are using multiple certificates on 1 ip address, this could be the issue:

http://javabreaks.blogspot.com/2015/12/java-ssl-handshake-with-server-name.html